# Error Emacs slime: eval-buffer: Symbol's function definition is void: define-slime-contrib

Tags: emacs, slime

I'm using emacs with lisp (using slime) for a short time...this work but today when I run it appear this message:

eval-buffer: Symbol's function definition is void: define-slime-contrib

means this than my slime contrib folder is not found?

my .emacs is a disaster..sorry for this...I search inside all the folders and everyone look well...

```
;; SLIME ==================================================
'

;; Orden: M-x slime
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/clisp")  ; 


(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")


;;(require 'slime-autoloads)                    
(add-to-list 'load-path "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/")                        ;; I review all this folders and
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/")       ;; the address look good
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/doc/slime/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/contrib/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(require 'slime)  

(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))

(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the relevant part of my .emacs:

```
  (setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/bin/sbcl") 
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/slime/") 
  (require 'slime)
  (slime-setup)
```

When using it, I go to the Lisp buffer and run `M-x slime` and voila, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your .emacs file from what you had to the following:

```
;; SLIME ==================================================

;; Orden: M-x slime
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/clisp")

(add-to-list 'load-path "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/")                        ;; I review all this folders and
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/")       ;; the address look good
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")

(require 'slime)  
(slime-setup)

(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))

(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))
```